# Tasker - Advance Settings - Export App Package Name?

Tags: applications, tasker

I've deactivated beginner mode on tasker and noticed now when I try exporting a task as an application it requires a Package name, I've tried following their instructions and have been unsuccessful, I don't want to go back to beginner mode therefore it is not an option

Does anyone know what's needed in the Package name with examples of what would work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you putting in for the package name that it doesn't like? Beginner mode vs non-beginner mode shouldn't matter.

Package name has to have at least one . in it to be valid.  Usually you can just use your email backwards along with a unique name for the app.  Say your email is someone@gmail.com and you're trying to export an app you want to call myapp.  The package name could be com.gmail.someone.myapp.